# Trying to encode using H264 for HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding, http-live-streaming, xuggle

I am trying to encode media files to use for HTTP Live Streaming, but don't have much luck so far. When I use the ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG2TS or ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4 codes the stream encode but I get an error using Apple's Validation tool:

> ERROR: (-12971) MPEG2 parser corrupt stream (program 1, track 257)
>   ERROR: (-12971) failed to parse segment as either an MPEG-2 TS or an
>   ES

If I save them as .mp4 instead of .ts then they play in Quicktime (but not as .ts)

If I use ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264 I get the following error when encoding:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: could not open stream
>   com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream@-397916640[index:0;id:1;streamcoder:com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder@-397916528[codec=com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@-397916032[type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO;id=CODEC_ID_H264;name=libx264;];time
>   base=1/25;frame rate=0/0;pixel
>   type=YUV420P;width=640;height=360;];framerate:0/0;timebase:1/90000;direction:OUTBOUND;]: Operation not permitted

I have the following settings for the encoder:

```
        coderSettings.width = 640;
        coderSettings.height = 360;
        coderSettings.bitRate = 700000;
        coderSettings.codec = ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264;
        coderSettings.globalQuality = 75;
        coderSettings.sampleRate = 22050;
```

I am just wondering if I do something wrong. I don't know that much of video encoding, so might just have forgotten a simple option when trying to encode to H264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed with the new version of Xuggler 5.5. However, it seems that it used the mpeg2ts encoder even when specifying the H264 encoder (on basis of the extension). This gives problems with QT and iOS devices.

With using FFMPEG directly it might works somewhat better as there is more control.

Answer (score 0):

Is xuggler a requirement? If not, it's possible to prepare assets using ffmpeg (the base of xuggler), for example with [these instructions](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/).

Comment: Thanks, I could, but by using Xuggler I can segment on the fly and also keep better track of encoding progress.

Comment: New versions of ffmpeg can segment on the fly, but I'm sure you're right that it is easier to track the encoding progress with Xuggler.

Comment: Do you actually know which version supports this? I checked out the SVN and build, but the segment options are unknown. I am more or less moving to use FFMPEG directly after all, as Xuggler seems to be very complicated to do EXACTLY what you want if it comes to the encoder.

Comment: It was added Mon, 19 Dec 2011.
http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?a=commit;h=02e8f03296d29949a7cffc8fa3e704b0efa66f17

Comment: Thanks vipw! It is included in 0.10.2 and I managed to build it on my production box. Now just some little issues to iron out, like the fact that the segmented doesn't seem to segment audio. But I will port another question on that one.